# formatting formset results values not input

Tags: django, django-templates

my template looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {{ formset.management_form }}
  {% for form in formset.forms %}
    {{ form.contractor }} {{ form.date }} {{ form.value }} {{ form.comment }} {{ form.operation_type }} {{ form.category }} {{ form.account }}
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```

but the result allows to change all of fields - but i want only one.

I thought that (please notice ".value" after all but category field) solves the problem, but not.

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {{ formset.management_form }}
  {% for form in formset.forms %}
    {{ form.contractor.value }} {{ form.date.value }} {{ form.value.value }} {{ form.comment.value }} {{   form.operation_type.value }} {{ form.category }} {{ form.account.value }}
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```

**UPD**:
relevant view code

```
def detail(request, category_id):
  from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
  OperationFormSet = modelformset_factory(Operation)
  if request.method == "POST":
    formset = OperationFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
                                queryset=Operation.objects.filter(category=category_id))
    if formset.is_valid():
      formset.save()
      # Do something.
  else:
    formset = OperationFormSet(queryset=Operation.objects.filter(category=category_id))
  return render_to_response("reports/operation_list.html", {
    "formset": formset,
  })
```

Comment: Please post the relevant view code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the readonly values are NOT passed back to the server, and thus your formset should fail as it's only receiving one field.

You'd want to show the value AND set a hidden field to store the data the formset is expecting. But I'd recommend a different approach...

Ultimately, a formset and form is used to display html forms and not built for anything else. You'd have to hack it to show hidden widgets, make sure users can't POST arbitrary data, etc. So instead, I would use the forms framework to only display your one editable field.

Create a `ModelForm` that only has one editable field

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Operation
        fields = ('category',)

MyModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(Operation, form=MyModelForm)
```

As for displaying values in the template, ModelForms should have their instance directly accessible via `form.instance` so you should be able to do something like this:

```
{% for form in formset %}
   {{ form.instance.some_attribute }}
   {{ form.category }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes! this is it! But now i have problems with ("Key 'form-0-id' not found in <QueryDict: {u'form-3-category': [u'15'],)